# Can ehcache monitor be configured over https?

Tags: ehcache

I have an application that is running on a secure site and I installed the ehcache probe jar. Everything seems to be running but I can't access it through the browser because by default the server is running on secure https.

Is there a way to view the monitor through https://myserver.com:9889/monitor?

I'm using the 30-day trial development version of ehcache monitor. Could this be the problem and perhaps the paid production version works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a free version and some resources maybe are not working or has a restriction , remember all that is free won't work perfect.

Comment: Right, I just want to make sure before going forth with the subscription that it will work. Thanks